# Use object as variable for function

Tags: function, vba, object

I'm trying to create a function called wait that would use an object:

```
Function wait(browser As Object)
            ' loop until the page finishes loading
            Do While browser.READYSTATE <> 4
            Loop
End Function
```

I also have:

```
Function GetIE() As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set GetIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End Function
```

and:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = GetIE


sURL = "http://google.com"

wait (appIE)
```

But i'm getting "Run time error '424'; Object required.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
wait (appIE)
```

to

```
wait appIE
```

**Explanation**: In VBA, whenever you call a Function that has parameters, if you are not doing anything with the return value, then you have to call it without the parenthesis. In this case, since the code is not returning anything, it should be defined as a `Sub` and not a `Function`. The same thing applies to `Sub` routines that take parameters also, i.e. you have to call it without parenthesis with the parameters separated by comma.

Further Reading (via [@doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy)) : [Quick VBA Tip: Parentheses](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/)

Comment: The GetIE function is working properly, the error was thrown when i have added the wait function

Comment: @AdamVoga Agreed. I just tested your code in Excel and located the problem. See my updated answer above.

Comment: why do the brackets make a difference?  Is it something to do with 'making a copy'?

Comment: This works! Can you let me know what is the difference between the two commands? Leaving "()" is kind of unusual to me

Comment: @AdamVoga Just updated answer with explanation so others can also benefit from it.

Comment: +1, for even more about this, read this [DDOE post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/),